# Navigation controller navigate from startDestination fragment getting exception

Tags: android, navigationcontroller, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ID does not reference a View inside this Activity

    mBtHome.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {



                    Navigation.findNavController(getActivity(), R.id.homePageFragment);
                }
            });
```

mBtHome button inside startDestination fragment

navigation graph xml file.

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_file"
    app:startDestination="@id/mainFragment">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mainFragment"
        android:name="com.example.libin.navigationhelphertest.ui.main.MainFragment"
        android:label="main_fragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/main_fragment">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_mainFragment_to_homePageFragment"
            app:destination="@id/homePageFragment" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_mainFragment_to_usersListFragment"
            app:destination="@id/usersListFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/homePageFragment"
        android:name="com.example.libin.navigationhelphertest.ui.main.HomePageFragment"
        android:label="fragment_home_page"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home_page" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/usersListFragment"
        android:name="com.example.libin.navigationhelphertest.ui.main.UsersListFragment"
        android:label="fragment_users_list"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_users_list" />
</navigation>
```

navigation/nav_file added inside MainActivity xml file  NavHostFragment alsoe included ,Also defaultNavHost= "true" added

Comment: Can you please post your navigation graph xml file?

Comment: @Android_team edited with xml

Comment: So from your MainFragment you are  doing this code and navigating to Home Fragemt right ?mBtHome.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {



                    Navigation.findNavController(getActivity(), R.id.homePageFragment);
                }
            });

Comment: That's it. I have two actions

Comment: @LibinThomas you got the answer?

Answer (score 6):

As per the above code to navigate from one fragment to another on click of the button, there are many ways.

Navigation class gives you the createNavigateOnClickListner() method you just need to pass the fragment action id.

Try the below code

```
 mBtHome.setOnClickListener(Navigation.createNavigateOnClickListener(R.id.action_mainFragment_to_homePageFragment));
```

Comment: I've never seen any sample use `createNavigateOnClickListener`.  Is that documented in JetPack?

Comment: Yes, it is documented in its developer's site for navigation. Please check below link  https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/Navigation

Comment: Why isn't that demonstrated in any Google samples, or any samples at all?

Comment: No, It is used in codelab code too.See the below link https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-navigation/#6

Comment: Neither Sunflower sample, Tivi sample, ioSched sample, nor Plaid google sample demonstrates this API.  Why?  Also, why is this API preferable to NavGraph Directions API?

Answer (score 4):

R.id.homePageFragment is not a NavHostFragment
do it like thie

```
        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container_view"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/motion_layout_graph" />
```

and call in code like this

```
                Navigation.findNavController(requireActivity(), R.id.fragment_container_view).navigate(R.id.show_one)
```